# _add_ vs _radd_: how the expressions are evaluated?

Tags: python

Let's consider the next example with classes:

```
class A1:
    def __init__ (self):pass
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A2):return 111
        if isinstance(other, A1):return 222
        return 333
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A1):return 444
        return 555

class A2(A1):
    def __init__(self) : pass
    def __radd__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, A1):return 666
        return 777
```

So, when I evaluate the following expressions

```
a1 = A1()
a2 = A2()
print(a1 + a1, a2 + a2, a1 + a2, a2 + a1)
```

I get this result:

```
222 111 666 222
```

I understand how I get 222, 111, 222 but how is it possible that **a1 + a2** evaluates to 666? Doesn't **a1** have add method with **other** being an instance of A2 which would result in 111 instead of 666?

The version of Python I'm using is 3.8.2

Comment: In python 2.7 it prints (222,111,111.222). which version of python do you use?

Comment: @napuzba I'm using 3.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `x + y`, if `y` is an instance of a subclass of `x`'s class, `y.__radd__` is tried *before* `x.__add__`. You're seeing that here.

Comment: why there is a difference between python2 and python3?

Comment: @napuzba: You need to have `A1` explicitly inherit from `object` on Python 2, or you get an old-style class, which have all sorts of weird quirks and shouldn't be used.

Comment: yes, if A1 inherits from object - it works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe A2 has also instance of A1 in that case and it returns 666 after all.