# Why is the following output giving the response instead of what I am expecting?

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
a=open("example.nx",'r').read()
b=a.replace("\n","").replace("  ","").split("|")
for i in b: 
    if (len(i)==2 or len(i)==1) and i.__contains__("}") or i.__contains__(")"):
        """doesn't belong is probably a closing bracket"""
        index=b.index(i)
        b[index-1]=b[index-1]+b[index]#add the closing brackets to the one before deleting it
        del b[index]
    """check for brackets opened that aren't closed"""
    if (i.__contains__("(") and not i.__contains__(")")) or (i.__contains__("{") and not i.__contains__("}")):
        #these are not closed
        index=b.index(i)
        if b[index+1].__contains__(")") or b[index+1].__contains__("}"):
            #add them together then delete the extra
            b[index]=b[index]+b[index+1]
            del b[index+1] 
del b[len(b)-1]
print(b)
```

And I have the file `example.nx`:

```
bp myClass(
    myClass[arg1]{
        set myArg to arg1|
    }
)|
def myFunction[arg2,arg3]{
    set a to arg2|
    set b to arg3|
}|
set var1 to 3|
set var2 to 4|
myFunction(var1,var2)|
```

I get the output of:

```
['bp myClass(myClass[arg1]{set myArg to arg1})', 'def myFunction[arg2,arg3]{set a to arg2', 'set b to arg3}', 'set var1 to 3', 'set var2 to 4myFunction(var1,var2)']
```

I was expecting to get(Look at last elements):

```
['bp myClass(myClass[arg1]{set myArg to arg1})', 'def myFunction[arg2,arg3]{set a to arg2', 'set b to arg3}', 'set var1 to 3', 'set var2 to 4','myFunction(var1,var2)']
```

I have added breakpoints and have broken the issue down to this block:

```
if (len(i)==2 or len(i)==1) and i.__contains__("}") or i.__contains__(")"):
        """doesn't belong is probably a closing bracket"""
        index=b.index(i)
        b[index-1]=b[index-1]+b[index]#add the closing brackets to the one before deleting it
        del b[index]
```

I don't know why this is happening because at the end of the list where the 2 elements merge they don't fit the length requirements so they shouldn't even set off the if statement.

Comment: Don't call `.__contains__()` directly; use `'(' in whatever`.

Comment: *"they don't fit the length requirements so they shouldn't even set off the if statement."* If `i.__contains__(")")` is true, the whole if-condition is True - you may want additional parentheses here.

Comment: To quickly demonstrate the behaviour of that statement: observe that `(False and False) and False or True` is True.

Comment: Thank you I completely missed that, although just for reference why not call  __contains__()?

Comment: `if x in y` is more general than `if y.__contains__(x)`. There are some objects which don't implement `__contains__` but can still be used with `in`: see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations

Comment: Calling magic methods directly is unconventional and is often frowned upon.

Comment: Aren't they technically called anyway?

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no - the details are meant to be abstracted from the programmer. For example, `x in y` often calls `y.__contains__(x)` but not always (see earlier link), and `a + b` often calls `a.__add__(b)` but not always (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/65133431/765091). The idea is that as a programmer you use the relevant operator (`in`, `+`, `-`) etc and let Python take care of calling the appropriate magic methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis in the first if:

```
txt = """
bp myClass(
    myClass[arg1]{
        set myArg to arg1|
    }
)|
def myFunction[arg2,arg3]{
    set a to arg2|
    set b to arg3|
}|
set var1 to 3|
set var2 to 4|
myFunction(var1,var2)|
"""
tokens = txt.replace('\n', '').replace("  ","").split("|")

for token in tokens: 
    if (len(token) == 2 or len(token) == 1) and ('}' in token or ')' in token):
        # these are missing                     ^                            ^
        # doesn't belong is probably a closing bracket
        i = tokens.index(token)
        tokens[i - 1] = tokens[i-1] + tokens[i]  # add the closing brackets to the one before deleting it
        del tokens[i]
    # check for brackets opened that aren't closed
    if ('(' in token and ')' not in token) or ('{' in token and '}' not in token):
        # these are not closed
        i = tokens.index(token)
        if ')' in tokens[i+1] or '}' in tokens[i+1]:
            # add them together then delete the extra
            tokens[i] = tokens[i] + tokens[i+1]
            del tokens[i+1] 
del tokens[len(tokens)-1]
print(tokens)
```

I've also changed your variables around, `a` and `b` are not good variable names. `i` can be a good variable name, if it is used as an integer index into a list.